# Copying assets folder subdirectories to specific folder in external storage

Tags: java, android, android-assets

I am using ProgramAB with Android which requires me to copy aiml files from assets folder to the external storage by creating /bots/ directory in it. This is the code I took from [this](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-baking-a-simple-chatbot-in-30-minutes-aiml-ff43c3269025) tutorial which teaches about chatbots in android (The other functions called in this code have nothing to do with directory copying).

I have tried the other solutions but nothing worked for me.

```
   //checking SD card availablility
        boolean a = isSDCARDAvailable();
        //receiving the assets from the app directory
        AssetManager assets = getResources().getAssets();
        File jayDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/hari/bots/Hari");
        boolean b = jayDir.mkdirs();
        if (jayDir.exists()) {
            //Reading the file
            try {
                for (String dir : assets.list("Hari")) {
                    File subdir = new File(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir);
                    boolean subdir_check = subdir.mkdirs();
                    for (String file : assets.list("Hari/" + dir)) {
                        File f = new File(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        InputStream in = null;
                        OutputStream out = null;
                        in = assets.open("Hari/" + dir + "/" + file);
                        out = new FileOutputStream(jayDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                        //copy file from assets to the mobile's SD card or any secondary memory
                        copyFile(in, out);
                        in.close();
                        in = null;
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                        out = null;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //get the working directory
        MagicStrings.root_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/hari";
        System.out.println("Working Directory = " + MagicStrings.root_path);
        AIMLProcessor.extension =  new PCAIMLProcessorExtension();
        //Assign the AIML files to bot for processing  
        bot = new Bot("Hari", MagicStrings.root_path, "chat");
        chat = new Chat(bot);
        String[] args = null;
        mainFunction(args);
```

Comment: `boolean b = jayDir.mkdirs();`. You should only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if mkdirs returns false you should display a toast to the user telling so. And return. Now you blindly continue. Please adalt your code.

Comment: @greenapps I am really new to android and I am not even able to check whether the copying is actually happening or not. Is the code not performing the task because of your stated issue?

Comment: You should tell us what does work and what does not work. Use log statements and toast to see what happens. Do some basic debugging.

Comment: Actually I am using visual studio emulator so debugging becomes more like an overhead because of adb linking troubles and all. Will customise the code to suit for public reference asap. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working fabulously.
Here's the whole [tutorial](http://www.twodee.org/blog/?p=4518).

```
/**
 * Copy the asset at the specified path to this app's data directory. If the
 * asset is a directory, its contents are also copied.
 * 
 * @param path
 * Path to asset, relative to app's assets directory.
 */
private void copyAsset(String path) {
  AssetManager manager = getAssets();

  // If we have a directory, we make it and recurse. If a file, we copy its
  // contents.
  try {
    String[] contents = manager.list(path);

    // The documentation suggests that list throws an IOException, but doesn't
    // say under what conditions. It'd be nice if it did so when the path was
    // to a file. That doesn't appear to be the case. If the returned array is
    // null or has 0 length, we assume the path is to a file. This means empty
    // directories will get turned into files.
    if (contents == null || contents.length == 0)
      throw new IOException();

    // Make the directory.
    File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Recurse on the contents.
    for (String entry : contents) {
      copyAsset(path + "/" + entry);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    copyFileAsset(path);
  }
}

/**
 * Copy the asset file specified by path to app's data directory. Assumes
 * parent directories have already been created.
 * 
 * @param path
 * Path to asset, relative to app's assets directory.
 */
private void copyFileAsset(String path) {
  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);
  try {
    InputStream in = getAssets().open(path);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = in.read(buffer);
    while (read != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      read = in.read(buffer);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working perfectly! I had followed the same blog actually :)